# Mindmap/trees in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, mindmaps

I can't get the following tikz examples to work (PGF manual 2.10, page 255). Most likely I can find a solution here that will save me time.

Error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \pgf@arrows@invertserif cm
l.55 ...ck}{green!25!black}{green}{green!80}{leaf}
```

BTW: It would have been nice to have the necessary libraries listed with the examples in the manual.

Example 1:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\tikzset{
  ld/.style={level distance=#1},lw/.style={line width=#1},
  level 1/.style={ld=4.5mm, trunk, lw=1ex ,sibling angle=60},
  level 2/.style={ld=3.5mm, trunk!80!leaf a,lw=.8ex,sibling angle=56},
  level 3/.style={ld=2.75mm,trunk!60!leaf a,lw=.6ex,sibling angle=52},
  level 4/.style={ld=2mm, trunk!40!leaf a,lw=.4ex,sibling angle=48},
  level 5/.style={ld=1mm, trunk!20!leaf a,lw=.3ex,sibling angle=44},
  level 6/.style={ld=1.75mm,leaf a, lw=.2ex,sibling angle=40},
}
\pgfarrowsdeclare{leaf}{leaf}
  {\pgfarrowsleftextend{-2pt} \pgfarrowsrightextend{1pt}}
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-2pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpatharc{150}{30}{1.8pt}
    \pgfpatharc{-30}{-150}{1.8pt}
    \pgfusepathqfill
  }
\newcommand{\logo}[5]{%
  \colorlet{border}{#1}
  \colorlet{trunk}{#2}
  \colorlet{leaf a}{#3}
  \colorlet{leaf b}{#4}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \scriptsize\scshape
    \draw[border,line width=1ex,yshift=.3cm,
      yscale=1.45,xscale=1.05,looseness=1.42]
      (1,0) to [out=90, in=0] (0,1) to [out=180,in=90] (-1,0)
      to [out=-90,in=-180] (0,-1) to [out=0, in=-90] (1,0) -- cycle;
    \coordinate (root) [grow cyclic,rotate=90]
      child {
        child [line cap=round] foreach \a in {0,1} {
          child foreach \b in {0,1} {
            child foreach \c in {0,1} {
              child foreach \d in {0,1} {
              child foreach \leafcolor in {leaf a,leaf b}
                { edge from parent [color=\leafcolor,-#5] }
              }
            }
          }
        } edge from parent [shorten >=-1pt,serif cm-,line cap=butt]
      };
    \node [align=center,below] at (0pt,-.5ex){
      \textcolor{border}{T}heoretical \\ \textcolor{border}{C}omputer \\
      \textcolor{border}{S}cience
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\logo{green!80!black}{green!25!black}{green}{green!80}{leaf}\\
\logo{green!50!black}{black}{green!80!black}{red!80!green}{leaf}\\
\logo{red!75!black}{red!25!black}{red!75!black}{orange}{leaf}\\
\logo{black!50}{black}{black!50}{black!25}{}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Example 2:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mindmap,
  every node/.style={concept, execute at begin node=\hskip0pt},
  root concept/.append style={
    concept color=black, fill=white, line width=1ex, text=black
  },
  text=white, grow cyclic,
  level 1/.append style={level distance=4.5cm,sibling angle=90},
  level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45}
]
\clip (0,-1) rectangle ++(4,5);
\node [root concept] {Computational Complexity}
  child [concept color=red] { node {Computational Problems}
    child { node {Problem Measures} }
    ... 
  }
  child [concept color=blue] { node {Computational Models}
    child { node {Turing Machines} }
    ...
  }
  child [concept color=orange] { node {Measuring Complexity}
    child { node {Complexity Measures} }
    ...
  }
  child [concept color=green!50!black] { node {Solving Problems}
    child { node {Exact Algorithms} }
    ...
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to Medina. Here is what I wanted to do:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) You need the `arrows` library (not explicitly mentioning all the libraries needed for the examples is very common in the manual):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,arrows}

\tikzset{
  ld/.style={level distance=#1},lw/.style={line width=#1},
  level 1/.style={ld=4.5mm, trunk, lw=1ex ,sibling angle=60},
  level 2/.style={ld=3.5mm, trunk!80!leaf a,lw=.8ex,sibling angle=56},
  level 3/.style={ld=2.75mm,trunk!60!leaf a,lw=.6ex,sibling angle=52},
  level 4/.style={ld=2mm, trunk!40!leaf a,lw=.4ex,sibling angle=48},
  level 5/.style={ld=1mm, trunk!20!leaf a,lw=.3ex,sibling angle=44},
  level 6/.style={ld=1.75mm,leaf a, lw=.2ex,sibling angle=40},
}
\pgfarrowsdeclare{leaf}{leaf}
  {\pgfarrowsleftextend{-2pt} \pgfarrowsrightextend{1pt}}
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-2pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpatharc{150}{30}{1.8pt}
    \pgfpatharc{-30}{-150}{1.8pt}
    \pgfusepathqfill
  }
\newcommand{\logo}[5]{%
  \colorlet{border}{#1}
  \colorlet{trunk}{#2}
  \colorlet{leaf a}{#3}
  \colorlet{leaf b}{#4}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \scriptsize\scshape
    \draw[border,line width=1ex,yshift=.3cm,
      yscale=1.45,xscale=1.05,looseness=1.42]
      (1,0) to [out=90, in=0] (0,1) to [out=180,in=90] (-1,0)
      to [out=-90,in=-180] (0,-1) to [out=0, in=-90] (1,0) -- cycle;
    \coordinate (root) [grow cyclic,rotate=90]
      child {
        child [line cap=round] foreach \a in {0,1} {
          child foreach \b in {0,1} {
            child foreach \c in {0,1} {
              child foreach \d in {0,1} {
              child foreach \leafcolor in {leaf a,leaf b}
                { edge from parent [color=\leafcolor,-#5] }
              }
            }
          }
        } edge from parent [shorten >=-1pt,serif cm-,line cap=butt]
      };
    \node [align=center,below] at (0pt,-.5ex){
      \textcolor{border}{T}heoretical \\ \textcolor{border}{C}omputer \\
      \textcolor{border}{S}cience
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\logo{green!80!black}{green!25!black}{green}{green!80}{leaf}\\
\logo{green!50!black}{black}{green!80!black}{red!80!green}{leaf}\\
\logo{red!75!black}{red!25!black}{red!75!black}{orange}{leaf}\\
\logo{black!50}{black}{black!50}{black!25}{}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The key to quickly guess where the problem was here is this line in the error message:

```
\pgf@arrows@invertserif
```

indicating some problem with related to arrows.

2) Remove the placeholders `...`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mindmap,
  every node/.style={concept, execute at begin node=\hskip0pt},
  root concept/.append style={
    concept color=black, fill=white, line width=1ex, text=black
  },
  text=white, grow cyclic,
  level 1/.append style={level distance=4.5cm,sibling angle=90},
  level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45}
]
\clip (0,-1) rectangle ++(4,5);
\node [root concept] {Computational Complexity}
  child [concept color=red] { node {Computational Problems}
    child { node {Problem Measures} } 
  }
  child [concept color=blue] { node {Computational Models}
    child { node {Turing Machines} }
  }
  child [concept color=orange] { node {Measuring Complexity}
    child { node {Complexity Measures} }
  }
  child [concept color=green!50!black] { node {Solving Problems}
    child { node {Exact Algorithms} }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or replace them with actual valid contents, for example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mindmap,
  every node/.style={concept, execute at begin node=\hskip0pt},
  root concept/.append style={
    concept color=black, fill=white, line width=1ex, text=black
  },
  text=white, grow cyclic,
  level 1/.append style={level distance=4.5cm,sibling angle=90},
  level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45}
]

\node[root concept] {Computational Complexity} % root
child[concept color=red] { node {Computational Problems}
child { node {Problem Measures} }
child { node {Problem Aspects} }
child { node {Problem Domains} }
child { node {Key Problems} }
}
child[concept color=blue] { node {Computational Models}
child { node {Turing Machines} }
child { node {Random-Access Machines} }
child { node {Circuits} }
child { node {Binary Decision Diagrams} }
child { node {Oracle Machines} }
child { node {Programming in Logic} }
}
child[concept color=orange] { node  {Measuring Complexity}
child { node {Complexity Measures} }
child { node {Classifying Complexity} }
child { node {Comparing Complexity} }
child { node {Describing Complexity} }
}
child[concept color=green!50!black] { node {Solving Problems}
child { node {Exact Algorithms} }
child { node {Randomization} }
child { node {Fixed-Parameter Algorithms} }
child { node {Parallel Computation} }
child { node {Partial Solutions} }
child { node {Approximation} }
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this case, with the original placeholders `...` you get an error message containing

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfutil@reserved@c ->\tikz@curveto@auto
```

The last part indicates that `TikZ` was trying to apply a `curveto` operation:  the parser took `..` as part of the `.. controls <point> ..` syntax for extending a path in a curved way but clearly the remaining code wasn't what the parser expected.