# Rotate entire tikzpicture without using graphics.sty

Tags: tikz-pgf

This question is related to the one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67191/mindmap-trees-in-tikz). The question is given in the following text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\tikzset{
  ld/.style={level distance=#1},lw/.style={line width=#1},
  level 1/.style={ld=4.5mm, trunk, lw=1ex ,sibling angle=60},
  level 2/.style={ld=3.5mm, trunk!80!leaf a,lw=.8ex,sibling angle=56},
  level 3/.style={ld=2.75mm,trunk!60!leaf a,lw=.6ex,sibling angle=52},
  level 4/.style={ld=2mm, trunk!40!leaf a,lw=.4ex,sibling angle=48},
  level 5/.style={ld=1mm, trunk!20!leaf a,lw=.3ex,sibling angle=44},
  level 6/.style={ld=1.75mm,leaf a, lw=.2ex,sibling angle=40},
}
\pgfarrowsdeclare{leaf}{leaf}{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{-2pt} \pgfarrowsrightextend{1pt}
}{
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-2pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpatharc{150}{30}{1.8pt}
  \pgfpatharc{-30}{-150}{1.8pt}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}

\makeatletter
\def\agobble#1\nil#2{}
\def\mytextcolor@a#1 #2\nil#3{%
  \mytextcolor@b#1\nil{#3}
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\expandafter\agobble\fi
  \mytextcolor@a#2\nil{#3}%
}
\def\mytextcolor@b#1#2\nil#3{%
  \textcolor{-#3}{\textbf{#1}}\textcolor{#3}{#2}\\
}
\def\mytextcolor#1#2{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\expandafter\agobble\fi
  \mytextcolor@a#2 \nil{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\logo}[8]{%
  \colorlet{border}{#1}
  \colorlet{trunk}{#2}
  \colorlet{leaf a}{#3}
  \colorlet{leaf b}{#4}
  % Question:
  % Which tikz feature can I use in place of the following \rotatebox
  % to avoid double rotation in the tikzpicture?
%  \rotatebox{#8}{%
    % One rotation is here:
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=#8,font=\scriptsize\scshape]
      \draw[border,line width=1ex,yshift=.3cm,
        yscale=1.45,xscale=1.05,looseness=1.42]
        (1,0) to [out=90, in=0] (0,1) to [out=180,in=90] (-1,0)
        to [out=-90,in=-180] (0,-1) to [out=0, in=-90] (1,0) -- cycle;
      \coordinate (root) [grow cyclic,rotate=90]
        child {
          child [line cap=round] foreach \a in {0,1} {
            child foreach \b in {0,1} {
              child foreach \c in {0,1} {
                child foreach \d in {0,1} {
                child foreach \leafcolor in {leaf a,leaf b}
                  { edge from parent [color=\leafcolor,-#5] }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          edge from parent [shorten >=-1pt,serif cm-,line cap=butt]
        };
      % Another rotation here:
      \node [rotate=#8,scale=1,align=center,below] at (0pt,-.5ex){%
        \mytextcolor{#6}{#7}\\
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
%  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
\logo{green!80!black}{green!25!black!75}{green}{green!80}{leaf}
  {border}{Theoretical Computer Science}{45}
\logo{purple!80!black}{purple!25!black!75}{purple}{purple!80}{leaf}
  {border}{Theoretical Computer Science}{45}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

The "double rotation" spots are shown above. I want to indicate only one rotation for the entire figure, because my figure contains many other nodes.

[image]

**EDIT**

The environment *scope* doesn't rotate the entire picture. Andrew Stacey has confirmed in the comments that this is indeed the case.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\tikzset{
  ld/.style={level distance=#1},lw/.style={line width=#1},
  level 1/.style={ld=4.5mm, trunk, lw=1ex ,sibling angle=60},
  level 2/.style={ld=3.5mm, trunk!80!leaf a,lw=.8ex,sibling angle=56},
  level 3/.style={ld=2.75mm,trunk!60!leaf a,lw=.6ex,sibling angle=52},
  level 4/.style={ld=2mm, trunk!40!leaf a,lw=.4ex,sibling angle=48},
  level 5/.style={ld=1mm, trunk!20!leaf a,lw=.3ex,sibling angle=44},
  level 6/.style={ld=1.75mm,leaf a, lw=.2ex,sibling angle=40},
}
\pgfarrowsdeclare{leaf}{leaf}{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{-2pt} \pgfarrowsrightextend{1pt}
}{
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-2pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpatharc{150}{30}{1.8pt}
  \pgfpatharc{-30}{-150}{1.8pt}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}

\makeatletter
\def\agobble#1\nil#2{}
\def\mytextcolor@a#1 #2\nil#3{%
  \mytextcolor@b#1\nil{#3}
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\expandafter\agobble\fi
  \mytextcolor@a#2\nil{#3}%
}
\def\mytextcolor@b#1#2\nil#3{%
  \textcolor{-#3}{\textbf{#1}}\textcolor{#3}{#2}\\
}
\def\mytextcolor#1#2{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\expandafter\agobble\fi
  \mytextcolor@a#2 \nil{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\logo}[8]{%
  \colorlet{border}{#1}
  \colorlet{trunk}{#2}
  \colorlet{leaf a}{#3}
  \colorlet{leaf b}{#4}
%  \rotatebox{#8}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize\scshape]
      \begin{scope}[rotate=#8]
      \draw[border,line width=1ex,yshift=.3cm,
        yscale=1.45,xscale=1.05,looseness=1.42]
        (1,0) to [out=90, in=0] (0,1) to [out=180,in=90] (-1,0)
        to [out=-90,in=-180] (0,-1) to [out=0, in=-90] (1,0) -- cycle;
      \coordinate (root) [grow cyclic,rotate=90]
        child {
          child [line cap=round] foreach \a in {0,1} {
            child foreach \b in {0,1} {
              child foreach \c in {0,1} {
                child foreach \d in {0,1} {
                child foreach \leafcolor in {leaf a,leaf b}
                  { edge from parent [color=\leafcolor,-#5] }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          edge from parent [shorten >=-1pt,serif cm-,line cap=butt]
        };
      \node [scale=1,align=center,below] at (0pt,-.5ex){%
        \mytextcolor{#6}{#7}\\
      };
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
\logo{green!80!black}{green!25!black!75}{green}{green!80}{leaf}
  {border}{Theoretical Computer Science}{45}
\logo{purple!80!black}{purple!25!black!75}{purple}{purple!80}{leaf}
  {border}{Theoretical Computer Science}{45}
\logo{purple!80!black}{purple!25!black!75}{purple}{purple!80}{leaf}
  {border}{}{45}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add a picture showing the double rotation that you'd like to avoid?  I get what looks like reasonable output with the code you post, but the `rotate=#8` key in the node makes me a little hesitant as to whether what I think is reasonable is what I'm meant to be seeing.

Comment: You can replace `rotate=#8` in the node by `transform shape` but I'm not sure to understand the question.

Comment: You could put everything into a `scope` and rotate that.

Comment: Ah, now I understand.  I thought that something was getting rotated twice but you mean that you have to specify the rotation twice.  In that case, I would try `every node/.append style={transform shape}` or `every node/.append style={rotate=#8}`.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Only `\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=#8,every node/.append style={rotate=#8}` seems to work. Note the double entry for *rotate*. Of course, we could take `every node/.append style={rotate=#8}` to `\tikzset`, but then `#8` can't be accessed directly.

Comment: Did you try the `transform shape` key?  The `scope` wouldn't work: a node is never transformed unless explicitly told to either by putting the transformation in its key list (directly, as your original solution, or indirectly via `every node`) or by using the magic key `transform shape`.

Comment: I have used `\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=#8,scale=\myscale,...]` with `\tikzset{...,every node/.append style={transform shape}}` and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

The node shape is almost like a standalone TikZ picture and before starting to draw the node shape, the transformation matrix is reset to identity matrix. Here are a couple of different cases

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=45,every node/.style={draw}]
\node (a) {A};
\node (b) at (1,0) {B};                   % Location obeys the transform
\node[transform shape] (c) at (-1,0) {C}; % Transformation is passed to the node too
\pgflowlevel{\pgftransformrotate{-45}}    % Works directly on the canvas,overrides anything, 
                                          % added to the current transformation, and 
                                          % the bounding box is not updated.
\node (d) at (1,0) {D}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am new to PGF and hadn't reached `\pgflowlevel` and `\pgftransformrotate`.

Comment: @AhmedMusa I'm sure it won't take too much time for you to start reading the source code and delve into the relevant keys :) So it's just a little overhead.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\tikzset{
  ld/.style={level distance=#1},lw/.style={line width=#1},
  level 1/.style={ld=4.5mm, trunk, lw=1ex ,sibling angle=60},
  level 2/.style={ld=3.5mm, trunk!80!leaf a,lw=.8ex,sibling angle=56},
  level 3/.style={ld=2.75mm,trunk!60!leaf a,lw=.6ex,sibling angle=52},
  level 4/.style={ld=2mm, trunk!40!leaf a,lw=.4ex,sibling angle=48},
  level 5/.style={ld=1mm, trunk!20!leaf a,lw=.3ex,sibling angle=44},
  level 6/.style={ld=1.75mm,leaf a, lw=.2ex,sibling angle=40},
}
\pgfarrowsdeclare{leaf}{leaf}{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{-2pt} \pgfarrowsrightextend{1pt}
}{
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-2pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpatharc{150}{30}{1.8pt}
  \pgfpatharc{-30}{-150}{1.8pt}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}

\makeatletter
\def\agobble#1\nil#2{}
\def\mytextcolor@a#1 #2\nil#3{%
  \mytextcolor@b#1\nil{#3}
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\expandafter\agobble\fi
  \mytextcolor@a#2\nil{#3}%
}
\def\mytextcolor@b#1#2\nil#3{%
  \textcolor{-#3}{\textbf{#1}}\textcolor{#3}{#2}\\
}
\def\mytextcolor#1#2{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\expandafter\agobble\fi
  \mytextcolor@a#2 \nil{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\logo}[8]{%
  \colorlet{border}{#1}
  \colorlet{trunk}{#2}
  \colorlet{leaf a}{#3}
  \colorlet{leaf b}{#4}
%  \rotatebox{#8}{%
%    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize\scshape]
      \begin{scope}[shift={(#8)}]
      \draw[border,line width=1ex,yshift=.3cm,
        yscale=1.45,xscale=1.05,looseness=1.42]
        (1,0) to [out=90, in=0] (0,1) to [out=180,in=90] (-1,0)
        to [out=-90,in=-180] (0,-1) to [out=0, in=-90] (1,0) -- cycle;
      \coordinate (root) [grow cyclic,rotate=90]
        child {
          child [line cap=round] foreach \a in {0,1} {
            child foreach \b in {0,1} {
              child foreach \c in {0,1} {
                child foreach \d in {0,1} {
                child foreach \leafcolor in {leaf a,leaf b}
                  { edge from parent [color=\leafcolor,-#5] }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          edge from parent [shorten >=-1pt,serif cm-,line cap=butt]
        };
      \node [scale=1,align=center,below,transform shape] at (0pt,-.5ex){%
        \mytextcolor{#6}{#7}\\
      };
    \end{scope}
%    \end{tikzpicture}
%  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize\scshape,rotate=45]
\logo{green!80!black}{green!25!black!75}{green}{green!80}{leaf}
  {border}{Theoretical Computer Science}{0,0}
\logo{purple!80!black}{purple!25!black!75}{purple}{purple!80}{leaf}
  {border}{Theoretical Computer Science}{3,0}
\logo{purple!80!black}{purple!25!black!75}{purple}{purple!80}{leaf}
  {border}{}{6,0}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- I removed the `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}` from the `\logo` command, so now you can't use it outside a `tikzpicture` environment anymore
- I redefined parameter `#8` to be a shift rather than a rotation
- The rotation is now added to the `tikzpicture` enclosing all `\logo` commands
- the `transform shape` is neccessary for the node texts to be rotated also

Comment: Great solution. The point was to avoid repeating `transform shape` and `rotate` per node.

Comment: If you don't want to set `transform shape` in every node, you could use the `every node` style via `every node/.style={transform shape}`