# Tikz: Using standalone

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

The following program copied from [Mindmap/trees in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67191/mindmap-trees-in-tikz) is compiling independently.

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mindmap,
  every node/.style={concept, execute at begin node=\hskip0pt},
  root concept/.append style={
    concept color=black, fill=white, line width=1ex, text=black
  },
  text=white, grow cyclic,
  level 1/.append style={level distance=4.5cm,sibling angle=90},
  level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45}
]

\node[root concept] {Computational Complexity} % root
child[concept color=red] { node {Computational Problems}
child { node {Problem Measures} }
child { node {Problem Aspects} }
child { node {Problem Domains} }
child { node {Key Problems} }
}
child[concept color=blue] { node {Computational Models}
child { node {Turing Machines} }
child { node {Random-Access Machines} }
child { node {Circuits} }
child { node {Binary Decision Diagrams} }
child { node {Oracle Machines} }
child { node {Programming in Logic} }
}
child[concept color=orange] { node  {Measuring Complexity}
child { node {Complexity Measures} }
child { node {Classifying Complexity} }
child { node {Comparing Complexity} }
child { node {Describing Complexity} }
}
child[concept color=green!50!black] { node {Solving Problems}
child { node {Exact Algorithms} }
child { node {Randomization} }
child { node {Fixed-Parameter Algorithms} }
child { node {Parallel Computation} }
child { node {Partial Solutions} }
child { node {Approximation} }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

However, when I try to include this file in my main document using the following, I get an error.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]

\includestandalone[width=.8\textwidth]{figures/mindMapExample}

\end{figure}
```

The error says: `pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tikz/mindmap' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ]`

How to resolve it?

Comment: Please provide a complete example of your main document. Do you load the `standalone` package? Which TikZ-packages are loaded...

Comment: You need `\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}` in the main document.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments, use `standalone` and `mindmap` packages:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage{subfig} % make it possible to include more than one captioned figure/table in a single float
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\title{Tikz: Using standalone}
\author{Sooraj}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Computional complexity}
Now, when I try to include this file in my main document using the following, I get this:
\begin{figure}[h!]
\includestandalone[width=.8\textwidth]{figures/mindMapExample}
\caption{Blablabla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`includestandalone` presumes that all the needed packages are already loaded by main..

In result you get this:

[image]

Comment: You could also use the `subpreambles` option for the `standalone` package to prevent the need for duplicating includes of TikZ libraries: `\usepackage{standalone}[subpreambles=true]`